# Stacked Barplot issue in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, bar-chart

I have a data frame matrix (see pic1), and am trying to create a stacked barplot with the column variables on the x axis. Using the following code,

```
barplot(as.matrix(africana06, beside=FALSE, legend=TRUE, ylab=c("Relative Total Damage"), xlab=c("Damage Type"), ylim=c(0,200), col=terrain.colors(4)))
```

I get a stacked barplot (see pic2), but it does not seem to take any of the arguments in my code. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Ryan

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpOl6.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TglPk.png)

Comment: Please don't post your data as a picture! The issue might simply be, that all the arguments (`beside = FALSE`, `legend = TRUE`, etc.) are actually passed to `as.matrix()`, not `barplot()`. Add a closing bracket after `africana06` (and remove one closing bracket at the end) .

Comment: Thank you so much, you were absolutely right! As always with R, the errors are usually easily fixable! Cheers for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The issue might simply be, that all the arguments (beside = FALSE, legend = TRUE, etc.) are actually passed to as.matrix(), not barplot(). Add a closing bracket after africana06 (and remove one closing bracket at the end) . – Stibu"